# I need to extract value of code field using sql regex function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

`{Type=connect List,  Value = Non Billable ,Code=M-1012,Listitemid= xyshdjf}`

need to extract the "CODE" value using SQL regex.It not jason format

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select text, regexp_extract(text, r'Code=(.*?)(?:,|})') as code
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: @rudra - have you tried?